# Pandas Sort by Date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, datetime

I am currently trying to sort a pandas DataFrame, but I am getting a strange error with the data types. I believe .to_datetime converts the object into a numpy datetime object, so I am currently trying to sort with that datatype. Here is the error thrown.

```
result = op(x, y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'DatetimeArray'
```

Code:

```
df['quote_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['quote_datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors='coerce')

print(df[(df['quote_datetime'] > np.datetime64('2020-08-07T09:30')) & df['quote_datetime'] < np.datetime64('2020-08-07T10:00')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your second condition in brackets as well:

```
print(df[(df['quote_datetime'] > np.datetime64('2020-08-07T09:30')) & (df['quote_datetime'] < np.datetime64('2020-08-07T10:00'))])
```